# spork: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

I've just installed spork via adding the version to the gemfile and running bundle install.

When I `gem list` I can see `spork (0.8.4)` so the gem is installed.

Im still tyring to configure spork, so when I type `spork --bootstrap` or `spork -v` to get see the version i get `spork: command not found`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever spork was installed isn't in your `PATH`, which is where your prompt looks for commands you type.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having the same problem. How do you reinstall spork to your `PATH`? Or how do you tell your prompt where spork is?

Comment: This is a bit too technical for me :/   Translation?

Comment: @Justin How is programming not too technical for you then? I'm very confused.

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to teach myself RoR and I'm finding it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a mac spork gets installed with all of your gems, aka at '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/'. Don't know where they go on Ubuntu and in Windows find them under your ruby install.

Try adding /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.8.4/bin/ to your PATH.  PATH is where your computer looks for programs to run
On a mac edit ~/.bash_profile and add the line:
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.8.4/bin/
to the end

Then don't worry, we all go through learning pains!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having your gems installed under a directory in your `PATH` - which I thin should be handled for you if you are using RVM - be sure to call `spork` from your rails directory - `Rails.root`. It will not work outside your rails project.