# Configuring Spork with ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, bootstrapping, spork

I'm new to ruby. I'm watching Rails cast on Spork with Rspec and following the tutorial. I'm using just Ruby without Rails. I successfully installed the spork gem. But when I run the below command:

```
spork --bootstrap
```

it tells me

```
 bash: /usr/bin/spork: No such file or directory.
```

Please suggest me some way to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `rvm`, `rbenv` or the system-installed version of ruby? Try `bundle exec spork --bootstrap` for a start.

Comment: I'm not using Rails. So bundle exec spork --bootstrap returns Could not locate Gemfile. I'm not using rvm. And my ruby version is 1.9.3p194

Comment: Okay, so we have established that you are using the system-installed version of ruby. What if you enter `gem list spork`?

Comment: It might be a path problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906309/spork-command-not-found

Comment: Spork can be confusing to use. Because you're new to ruby, are you sure you need spork? It basically just speeds up tests, sort of, some of the time. If your goal is fast tests, this is a pretty amazing overview: http://grease-your-suite.herokuapp.com/#1

Comment: Before trying to use Spork I'd recommend getting a decent Ruby set-up on your system. Options have already been mentioned - take a look at [rvm](http://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Answer (score 1):

In the [railscasts episode on spork with rspec](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork), Ryan Bates uses `spork` to speed up a spec in a Rails app he built in a couple of previous episodes, starting with the one titled [How I Test](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test). It would be easier if you revisit those episodes and follow along with the steps with a rails app. Or start by downloading [the source code for the spork episode](https://github.com/railscasts/285-spork)

As many have commented above, (a) You don't need spork at this stage when you are just getting into ruby/rails, and (b) it is preferable you have a working ruby set-up with either `rvm` or `rbenv`.

An additional recommendation I would add is to go through to the freely available [Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) by Michael Hartl; it  is a good guide to learn about working in ruby/rails, and has up-to-date info about how to work with the various tools in the ruby/rails world - like `git`, `rspec`, `spork`, `rvm`, `bundler`, among others.